# Selenium WebDriver - How to find the index of line in table

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I want to find the index of row in table(10 rows) by Selenium:

```
<table _ngcontent-c4="" class="table table-striped table-br" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220451" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220452" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220453" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220454" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220455" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220456" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220457" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220458" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220459" xpath="1">
<tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220460" xpath="1">
```

The problem is to find the row with `plan_id ="41220457" (index = 7)`

I tried to use several locators, but no success.

Comment: Can you show what did you try so far?

Comment: The global problem is to click the button in table. I have to click on the button on lets say, the 7th row. I tried this: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//.../table[@class='table table-striped table-br']/tbody/tr[contains(@plan-id,'41220457')]/td[8]/div[1]/button[1]").Click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code with this below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@xpath='1']//tr[contains(@plan-id, '" + plan_id + "')]/td[8]/div[1]/button[1]/span[1]")).Click();
```

If you have only one button in the column 8, you can further simplify the line as below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@xpath='1']//tr[contains(@plan-id, '" + plan_id + "')]/td[8]//button/span[1]")).Click();
```

Btw, if anyone want to get the index number as posted in the original query, then you can run the below javascript using driver instance.

```
document.evaluate("//table[@xpath='1']//tr[@plan-id='41220457']/preceding-sibling::tr", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength+1
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]'

Answer (score 2):

Let find all table row as List

```
var table = chrome.FindElement(By.TagName("table"));
var tr = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

Comment: Ok, and then, how to find the index of this row <tr _ngcontent-c4="" plan-id="41220457" xpath="1">?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < tr.Count; i++)
{
        tr[i].GetAttribute("id");     //for getting id of each element
}
Compare it with a ID you want to find, you can get row index

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by this:
`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html[1]/body[1]/sk-app[1]/sk-internal-template[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/jhi-plan[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[contains(@plan-id, '" + plan_id + "')]/td[8]/div[1]/button[1]/span[1]")).Click();`